# Maximum Likelihood with heteroskedasticity

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, heteroscedasticity

Suppose I regress $y$ on an explanatory variable $x$, so $y= a+bx + e$ where $e \sim N(0,g(x))$. This means the errors are normally distributed but show heteroskedasticity.
In my model, $x$ is a binary variable that takes either 0 or 1.
Using maximum likelihood, how could I retrieve an estimate of $g(x = i)$ for $i \in \{0,1\}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem actually simplifies neatly.  Let's assume the data has been reordered so that the first $n_0$ observations are the ones for which $x=0$, and the next $n_1$ observations are the ones for which $x=1$, with $n=n_0+n_1$. We observe that, as $x$ is binary, there are just two values for $g(x)$; we write them as $\sigma^2_0$ and $\sigma^2_1$. Writing out the log-likelihood $l(a,b,\sigma^2_0, \sigma^2_1)$ results in:

$$l(a,b,\sigma^2_0,\sigma^2_1) = -{n_0\over 2}\log\sigma^2_0-{n_1\over 2}\log\sigma^2_1-\sum_{i=1}^{n_0}{(y_i-a)^2\over 2\sigma^2_0}-\sum_{i=n_0+1}^n{(y_i-a-b)^2\over 2\sigma^2_1}$$

We can rewrite the last term on the right hand side, defining $a^*=a+b$, as$\sum_{i=n_0+1}^n(y_i-a^*)^2/2\sigma^2_1$.  Our likelihood function now separates into two independent Gaussian likelihood functions:

$$l(a,b,\sigma^2_0,\sigma^2_1) = \left[-{n_0\over 2}\log\sigma^2_0-\sum_{i=1}^{n_0}{(y_i-a)^2\over 2\sigma^2_0}\right]+\left[-{n_1\over 2}\log\sigma^2_1-\sum_{i=n_0+1}^n{(y_i-a^*)^2\over 2\sigma^2_1}\right]$$

As we can see, the two bracketed terms don't share any parameters, so we can solve them separately and still get the jointly optimal solution.  The MLEs for $a$ and $\sigma^2_0$ are just the MLEs for the population mean and variance of a normal variate based on those observations for which $x=0$, and, similarly, the MLEs for $a^*$ and $\sigma^2_1$ are the MLEs for the population mean and variance of a normal variate based on those observations for which $x=1$.  If we wish to retrieve the MLE for $b$, it'll just be the difference between the MLEs of $a^*$ and $a$: $\hat{b} = \hat{a}^*-\hat{a}$.